# python 2 : Daemon threads not getting killed on KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, multithreading

I am writing a simple threaded application and i have set the thread as `daemon` because I wanted my program to exit at `KeyboardInterrupt`. This works fine and gives expected result with `python3` but `python2.7` does not seem to respect the `daemon` flag. Below is my sample code

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    try:
        threads = [Thread(target=some_func, args=(arg1,arg2)) for _ in range(10)]

        for th in threads:
            th.daemon=True
            th.start()

        for th in threads:
            th.join()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        sys.exit('Ctrl-c issued by user .. Exiting')
```

When i run this code on `python3` and then hit `ctrl-c` after a while my program exits as expected, but when i run this with `python2.7` and then hit `ctrl-c` it never exits and I have to kill the process from shell.

Am i missing something here ? I have also tried setting the `threading.Event` and then clearing the event when `KeyboardInterrupt` occurs but even that didn't work

With `python3` If I don't `join` my `daemon` threads then they would exit as soon as the my program is done, and if I don't mark my thread as `daemon` and don't `join` then the program continues and as soon as i hit `ctrl-c` it exits. But none of this works with `python2.7`

**Edit #1**

I did some more digging into it and it looks like `python2.7` is not able to catch `KeyboardInterrupt`. This is even more weird because `KeyboardInterrupt` works fine it is a non-threaded program but with threads the `KeyboardInterrupt` is not being caught even though the threads are marked as `daemon`.

All of this happens only on `python2.7` and `python3` works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

The way `Thread.join` works in older versions of Python can silently swallow signals until the `join` completes. This includes SIGINT aka KeyboardInterrupt.

As a workaround, you can try short `sleep` or `join`. If you expect your threads to die by themselves, make sure to clean up:

```
    while threads:
        threads[-1].join(1)  # allow KeyboardInterrup once per second
        if not threads[-1].is_alive():  # reap dead Threads
           threads.pop()
```

---

> My first thought was to use thread.join, but that seems to block the main process (ignoring KeyboardInterrupt) until the thread is finished.[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3788243/5349916)

---

> Multithreaded Python programs often ignore the SIGINT generated by a Keyboard Interrupt, especially if the thread that gets the signal is waiting or sleeping. [2](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/496735-workaround-for-missed-sigint-in-multithreaded-prog/)

---

> I'm using Python 2.7, and my program ignores SIGTERM signals when using 
>   ThreadPoolExecutor.
>
> After some debugging I found that my main thread is blocked on Thread.join(), 
>   and it holds the interruption until the call returns. [3](https://github.com/agronholm/pythonfutures/issues/25)

Comment: So this behavior is true for daemon threads as well ? Because it looks like this is happening for daemon threads in my case... and this seems to defeat the purpose of daemon threads then...

Comment: This is a sideeffect of join, not the Thread itself. It does not matter whether they are daemon or not. While you can use the workaround mentioned in the answer, be aware that Python 2.7 is practically ancient. The proper fix is to use a recent version, i.e. Python 3.X.

Comment: ofcourse i totally agree with you.. i was just testing some code on python2 and just observer this.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @MisterMiyagi for the suggestions and i was able to test some of the solutions mentioned in the https://stackoverflow.com/a/3788243/5349916.

Please note below solutions apply only to `daemon` threads because a non-daemon will always block the main program until it is done completing its work if you put the `join` on it. If you don't put a `join` on non-daemon threads then they will continue running in the background if your main has exited and this is expected behavior.

The issue I was having was for specifically for `daemon` threads. So here are the solutions.

**# 1:** Do not put a join on the thread as it will cause the thread to block the main process.  The works because `daemon` threads exits as soon as the main program exits, so when you are not putting a `join` then you are not waiting in the main program and this `time.sleep(1)` inside `while` is just to make sure `daemon` thread keeps on executing and as soon as i hit `ctrl-c`, main will exit and so does `daemon` thread with it.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        threads = [threading.Thread(name='daemon', target=daemon)
                   for _ in range(8)]

        for th in threads:
            th.daemon = True
            th.start()

    while True:
        time.sleep(1)
    # signal.pause()    # This worked fine for me on Linux, on Windows it doesn't work, not sure about Mac. I am not recommending this because of platform dependency.

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
```

**# 2:** If you want to put a `join` on the thread, use timeout with it and then keep it in a `while` loop checking till the `thread` is `alive`. What this will do is keep on the checking every thread in `threads` list until its alive and then wait for 1 sec to execute it. Now since `while` condition is going to be `True`  until the `Thread` is actually reaped after its completed; it will block the main program in small chunks of 1sec and once you hit the `ctrl-c` the `daemon thread` is not alive any more and hence main program exits.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        threads = [threading.Thread(name='daemon', target=daemon)
                   for _ in range(8)]
        for th in threads:
            th.daemon = True
            th.start()

        for th in threads:
            while th.isAlive():
                th.join(1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('ctrl-c')
```

Comment: @MisterMiyagi i think you are you are misunderstanding. `join(1)` runs till the time thread `isAlive` returns `True`. The `join(1)` will wait for 1 second and then return and thi will happen until the thread is running. So the thread will complete its execution until i hit `ctrl-c`.